# custom SPD workflow not working after server restart -'Failed on Start (retrying) '

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, 2007, infopath

MOSS 2007 WSS 3.0

Have an Infopath form library with custom SPD workflow which worked beautifully until the server was restarted.I can create basic workflows against this form library that will send me an email with field values, etc, but if I add conditions based on initiation or field values I fail...

Here are my logs

```
04/16/2012 11:13:15.21       w3wp.exe (0x17C4)                             0x12FC      Windows SharePoint Services         General                             0      Unexpected      ERROR: request not found in the TrackedRequests. We might be creating and closing webs on different threads. ThreadId = 10, Free call stack =    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRequestManager.Release(SPRequest request)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.Invalidate()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.Close()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.Close()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.Dispose()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowManager.<>c__DisplayClass1.<StartWorkflow>b__0()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.CodeToRunElevatedWrapper(Object state)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass4.<RunWithElevatedPrivileges>b__2()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithE...      
 04/16/2012 11:13:15.21*      w3wp.exe (0x17C4)                             0x12FC      Windows SharePoint Services         General                             0      Unexpected      ...levatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowManager.StartWorkflow(SPListItem item, SPWorkflowAssociation association, SPWorkflowEvent startEvent, Boolean bAutoStart, Boolean bCreateOnly)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowManager.StartWorkflow(SPListItem item, SPWorkflowAssociation association, String eventData, Boolean isAutoStart)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowManager.StartWorkflow(SPListItem item, SPWorkflowAssociation association, String eventData)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPWorkflowDataSourceView.Insert(IDictionaryvalues)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPWorkflowDataSourceView.In...      
 04/16/2012 11:13:15.21*      w3wp.exe (0x17C4)                             0x12FC      Windows SharePoint Services         General                             0      Unexpected      ...sert(IDictionary values, DataSourceViewOperationCallback callback)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.FlatCommit()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.PerformCommit()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.HandleOnSave(Object sender, EventArgs e)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)     at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)     at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean inclu...       
04/16/2012 11:13:15.21*      w3wp.exe (0x17C4)                             0x12FC      Windows SharePoint Services         General                             0      Unexpected      ...deStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)     at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr)     at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNoDemand(HttpWorkerRequest wr)     at Sy...      
 04/16/2012 11:13:15.21*      w3wp.exe (0x17C4)                             0x12FC      Windows SharePoint Services         General                             0      Unexpected      ...stem.Web.Hosting.ISAPIRuntime.ProcessRequest(IntPtr ecb, Int32 iWRType)  , Allocation call stack (if present) null      
 04/16/2012 11:13:15.19       w3wp.exe (0x17C4)                             0x1588      Windows SharePoint Services         Workflow Infrastructure             88xr      Unexpected      WinWF Internal Error, terminating workflow Id# 8710247a-28b9-4e54-8ed5-ffe6d698ff37      
 04/16/2012 11:13:15.74       w3wp.exe (0x17C4)                             0x16FC      CMS                                 Publishing                          0      Unexpected      While initializing navigation, found Area placeholder but object was not found at: /HR/PRIV.
```

Answer (score 1):

That last item in the log file reminds me of an issue I experienced a while back regarding workflows. Are you sure this is specifically targeted to your Forms Library. Do you have any pages in your publishing sites pages libraries that have workflows that have errored out, or have corrupt pages? If so stop those and possibly delete the page if it is throwing errors. Then check your workflows again.